# roughly 12px white space at bottom of page not attributed to any element?

Tags: html, css, drupal

I am getting 12px white space at the bottom of my pages. Upon inspecting the CSS it's not attributed to any element. According to CSS inspectors the height of both the body and html elements don't include this space...It's got me miffed.

The page is here if you want to take a look: [Page](http://funjable.com/rarediseaseproject/)

Thanks

Comment: Probably not related, but you have a double scrollbar. Website faux pas.

Comment: yea thanks, that happened while trying to fix the problem, got rid of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the #footer-wrapper to this it will fix your problem

```
#footer-wrapper {
    background-image: url('../images/green.jpg');
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will work, but it doesn't really solve the base problem. It just hides it. The issue is caused by the `content` of the `.clearfix` class.

Answer (score 6):

Change the content of your `.clearfix` from a `.` to `\0020` (which is a space). This will do the trick:

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "\0020"; /* change to this */
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

part of it is related to your `.clearfix::after`.  I added a `line-height:0` to that, and most of it went away.  I think your line-heights generally across the page are screwing with the layout a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change line-height or something, you can just add padding to your footer like this:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```